# Is SQL Server able to use internal parallelism for an update statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, update, parallelism

I am struggling to find the best way to migrate some "varchar" columns to "nvarchar". One of the options i am using is to add new nvarchar column(s) then update the values from the original column, drop the original column and rename the new one to the old name.

I know it will generate a lot of UNDO and REDO data. Still, I have other limitations (mostly by SQL Server not supporting parallel DDLs and multi-column ALTER table operations), so let's focus on how to run the update statement faster.

My Oracle experience is telling me to use internal parallelism, but is it available in SQL Server?

I am not able to run this statement in parallel, although I especially created the table to be a heap table (no clustered index).

```
update t
set new_col_1 = col_1
   ,new_col_2 = col_2
   ...
   , new_col_N = col_N
;
```

There are 3 text columns holding 400GB of data. There is limited IO performance from AWS RDS (10000 IOPS). We have just 4 hours of downtime window.

---

In this particular migration the online rebuild is not an option as the data must be migrated (to nvarchar) before the application can be started. During startup it is checking whether the actual data types correspond to the defined ones (in the application metadata repository).

I am aware of the fragmentation, but we just have no choice. Still, if there is some ONLINE rebuild command it might be useful as we will be able to migrate and de-fragment later. Actually, as one of the preparations steps, we are dropping the clustered index. Later this index will be created again, which i believe will fix the fragmentation issue, as we will move from a heap to b*tree structure.

It is very frustrating that we can not use any other "parallel" technique. I am thinking to try manual parallel update, by running a few parallel update statements against not overlapping ranges of the target table. Still, the lock escalation, could be the next issue, as i am going to update millions of records in each of those updates, and most probably the SQL server will try to escalate to table lock, which will lock other updates, and a dead lock will be the end result..

Comment: @PaulWhite, thanks for the feedback! ok, i updated the question. Still, i find comments keeping a track of how we are moving to the solution, which is also useful. Do you really need table DDL in this case ?! the question can be taken high level, and just check what options are available as native database support. Again, i don't see major changes in parallel operations (after 2014), which can support us here.. If any, again, we can upgrade if it worth it..

Comment: This is a Q & A site. Comments exist mostly temporarily to assist in clarifying unclear questions. Not providing information up front is just making everything harder and more time-consuming than it needs to be. Unclear questions are often ignored, closed, and eventually deleted because people's time is limited and there are other questions to answer.

Answer (score 10):

No, SQL Server does not support parallel update*. That said, it is unclear if parallelism would assist an I/O-bound operation in your scenario.

SQL Server does support [parallel insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/sqlcat/sqlsweet16-episode-3-parallel-insert-select) to a row store heap or clustered columnstore (with [restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/sqlcat/real-world-parallel-insert-what-else-you-need-to-know)), select into a new heap, and some parallel DDL operations like index building.

Depending on your version of SQL Server, the size and schema of the table in question, any relationships to other tables, and recovery model, you may find it faster to create a new table with the updated column data type using [parallelism and minimal logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql#remarks). You should test this option even with a limited I/O cloud subsystem, rather than assuming it would be too slow.

If you were on SQL Server 2016 or later, an [`ONLINE` alter column](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql#with--online--on--off-as-applies-to-altering-a-column) might also have been an option. This is limited to one column change at a time but is non-blocking. It also tends to result in a better-organized final result (fewer or no heap forwarded records).

If you are able to split the change across multiple maintenance window and have sufficient storage available, you could migrate gradually from one schema to another using a batch process and triggers to copy changes across during non-maintenance periods. The final step is to drop the old table and rename the new as described [here](https://am2.co/2019/12/changing-a-column-from-int-to-bigint-without-downtime/).

Some of the methods available to you might generate a lot of transaction log (as you mentioned). If you were able to upgrade to 2019 or later, [*Accelerated Database Recovery*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/accelerated-database-recovery-concepts) would allow aggressive log truncation (including for in-progress transactions), likely making this aspect a non-issue.

You should carefully consider your proposed method since the heap will still contain the dropped column until it is fully rebuilt, and the heap will have very many [forwarded records](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes#when-not-to-use-a-heap) as existing rows do not have enough space to hold the extra column data.

> Do not use a heap if the data is frequently updated. If you update a record and the update uses more space in the data pages than they are currently using, the record has to be moved to a data page that has enough free space. This creates a forwarded record pointing to the new location of the data, and forwarding pointer has to be written in the page that held that data previously, to indicate the new physical location. This introduces fragmentation in the heap. When scanning a heap, these pointers must be followed which limits read-ahead performance, and can incur additional I/O which reduces scan performance.

---

* The *update* itself is never performed by more than one thread. Other operators in an update execution plan may use parallelism. SQL Server also supports multiple concurrent updates to the same table from different connections of course, but with your table structured as a heap you likely have no way to ensure these updates could be efficiently disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16) depending on how the application code accesses the table. You can rename the old column, create a new NVARCHAR column, and create a new computed column with the original column name that returns either the new or old base column depending on which one is NULL. You can then transfer the data from the old base column to the new base column at your leisure. Once all of the data has been transferred you can get drop the computed column and the old base column and rename the new base column.

The advantage of this approach is that it can be completed with a minimum of downtime and your IOPS won't matter. The biggest disadvantage with this approach is that you cannot directly insert or update a computed column so you would need to redirect any code that does that to the new base column.

Example T-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T323266 (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    ORIGINAL_COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(2000) NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.T323266 (ID, ORIGINAL_COLUMN_NAME)
VALUES (1, 'test_data');

GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC sp_rename 'T323266.ORIGINAL_COLUMN_NAME', 'ORIGINAL_COLUMN_NAME_OLD_VARCHAR', 'COLUMN';

ALTER TABLE dbo.T323266
ADD ORIGINAL_COLUMN_NAME_NEW_NVARCHAR NVARCHAR(2000) NULL;

ALTER TABLE dbo.T323266
ADD ORIGINAL_COLUMN_NAME AS ISNULL(ORIGINAL_COLUMN_NAME_NEW_NVARCHAR, CAST(ORIGINAL_COLUMN_NAME_OLD_VARCHAR AS NVARCHAR(2000)));

COMMIT TRANSACTION;


-- WARNING: cannot insert or update the computed column so insert into the new NVARCHAR column instead
INSERT INTO dbo.T323266 (ID, ORIGINAL_COLUMN_NAME_NEW_NVARCHAR)
VALUES (2, 'test_data2');

SELECT ID, ORIGINAL_COLUMN_NAME
FROM T323266;
```

Comment: hm.. looks too risky for a production system.. otherwise, i agree it allows for minimal downtime.